# How get data from table with NHibernate by where?

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

I used in my project NHibernate like this:

```
public class DBHelper
    {
        private static ISessionFactory sessions;

        public static void Configure()
        {            
            sessions = new Configuration().Configure().AddClass(typeof(Clients)).BuildSessionFactory();
            //ISessionFactory factory = Fluently.Configure().Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Clients>()).Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey(DBConnection.GetConnectionString())).BuildSessionFactory();
        }

        public static void Insert(Clients pb)
        {            
            using (ISession session = sessions.OpenSession())           
            using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {                
                session.Save(pb);                
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }

        public static void UpdateContact(Clients pb)
        {
            using (ISession session = sessions.OpenSession())
            using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Update(pb);
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }

        public static void DeleteContact(Clients pb)
        {
            using (ISession session = sessions.OpenSession())
            using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Delete(pb);
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tree simple methods: insert, delete, save.
Now I need to get all data from DB table or some data like analog
     select * from Clients where id='...'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your options are:

- [Criteria Queries](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querycriteria.html)
- [QueryOver Queries](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryqueryover.html)
- [HQL](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryhql.html)
- [Linq](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html)
- [Native SQL](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html)

Personally, I really like the QueryOver API:

```
var clients = session.QueryOver<Clients>().Where(x => x.Name == "Foobar").List();
```

If you only need to get an entity by its ID, you can use [Get or Load](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-loading)

```
var client = session.Get<Clients>(5);
```

If you search for NHibernate tutorials you'll certainly find a lot of information. I've heard good things about the [Summer Of NHibernate screencasts](http://summerofnhibernate.com/), though I personally haven't seen them.

Comment: The first link "Criteria Queries" doesn't work anymore.